# Magit: Files missing in status buffer when "Ignore all whitespace" is enabled

Tags: magit

In Magit I sometimes toggle `Ignore all whitespace` in the status buffer. This causes files that contain only whitespace changes to disappear. This means I cannot operate on them without toggling `Ignore all whitespace` and refreshing. Is there any option to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Magit just runs `git diff --ignore-all-space ...`. That does not output files that contain only whitespace changes and so Magit doesn't display those either. I think it makes sense for Git/Magit to do that, it's kinda what you requested by using `--ignore-all-space`.

> This means I cannot operate on them

You should still be able to do so. Many commands that default to the file at point (with or without confirmation) instead ask you for a file when invoked while point is not on a file.

So for example to stage a file that only contains whitespace changes move point to something that cannot be staged (e.g. onto "Unmerged into master") and press <kbd>s</kbd> as usual and then select the file you want to stage.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I can stage it as you proposed and that is fine, but what I think I want is something similar to what `git status` gives me on the command line. Here I can see the staged file no matter what diff options I use.